# Trigger to copy few columns from table1 to table2 automatically when new data is imported into table1

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, triggers

I have a `table1` with columns (`date, field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6, field7, field8`)

I have another `table2` with columns (`date, field1,someothercolumns, field3, field5, field7, unrelatedcolumns1, someothercolumns2`)

Now every time when new data is imported into `table2`, I also want data from columns (`date, field1, field3, field5, field7`) from `table2` to automatically be copied into `table1` (`date, field1, field3, field5, field7`).

Missing columns in `table1` can have null values

Is it possible using trigger or any stored procedures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER YourTriggerName
ON dbo.Table2
AFTER INSERT 
AS BEGIN

   INSERT INTO dbo.Table1(date, field1, field3, field5, field7)
     SELECT
         date, field1, field3, field5, field7
     FROM
         Inserted
END
```

In a trigger, you can access the "pseudo" tables `Inserted` (and `Deleted` for `UPDATE` and `DELETE` triggers) which contains all rows that have been affected by the statement that caused the trigger to fire.

This is important : if you have an `INSERT` statement that inserts 10 rows, your trigger will fire **once** and the pseudo table `Inserted` will have 10 rows in it. Do not ever assume that your trigger fires once per row that's being inserted - that is not the case.

So in this trigger here, whenever an `INSERT` into `table2` has happened, the columns in question are extracted from the `Inserted` pseudo table and inserted into `table1`.

Does that solve your problem?

Comment: thanks marc_s...it solved my problem...but i just like to know if possible to insert one more column let's say field8 from table2 into table1 table1 provided field8 itself is a calculated column whose values are updated only when mporting from another trigger.

Comment: @user1449596, yes you can do that as long as you can do the calulation inteh insert statement.  The insert would be something like (I gave 3 exaplmes of calculatedf ields): INSERT INTO dbo.Table1(date, field1, field3, field5, field7, field8, field9, field10) 
SELECT date, field1, field3, field5, field7, field3-field7 as field8, 'test' as field9, getdate() as field10 
     FROM 
         Inserted